# Perl: Subroutine Output Showing Before Needed

Tags: linux, perl

I am completely new to perl and right now I am really stuck on this (probably really simple) problem. The problem itself is that of simple output issue where I am getting the results before they should be. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
sub above_average
{
        my $average = &average(@_);

        foreach my $thing (@_)
        {
                if ($thing > $average)
                {
                        print $thing;
                }
        }

}

my @fred = &above_average(1..10);

print "\@fred is @fred\n";
print "(Should be 6 7 8 9 10)\n";
```

The result that I get I get when I run the code is this:

```
678910@fred is 
(Should be 6 7 8 9 10)
```

It should look like `@fred is 6 7 8 9 10` and not `678910@fred is`. I just have no clue how to fix it, I've been at it for hours already with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your subroutine `print`s those numbers which are larger than average, it does not `return` them. But note that you can only return once from a subroutine, so we first have to collect all larger values:

```
sub above_average {
    my $avg = average(@_);
    return grep { $_ > $avg } @_;
}
```

which is a short way of expressing

```
sub above_average {
    my $avg = average(@_);
    my @out;
    for my $num (@_) {
        push @out, $num if $num > $avg;
    }
    return @out;
}
```

Tip: don't invoke your subroutines with a leading `&`, that's an unnecessary ancient habit, and has some effects you may not be aware of. Avoid it if possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you by any chance explain what `return grep { $_ > $avg } @_;` is basically doing? I am really knew to this and this is a little confusing for me...

Comment: @bloodstorm17 `grep { CONDITION } LIST` selects all elements from the list for which the condition holds true. My second code snippet with the `for` loop behaves equivalently to the `grep` solution.

Comment: @bloodstorm17: You could try reading the documentation for [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).